# Putting three headlights on my bike

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, headlight

I want to fit a total of three headlights on my average 220. What type of modifications do I need to make in the wiring to make it possible?

Comment: Use duct tape and a flashlight? Really, we are going to need a lot more information about your current bike to be able to even start to answer. What year/make/model is your bike? An "average 220" is really nondescript to me. Help us out here and we might be able to come up with some ideas.

Comment: Is that even legal where you are?  Changing light count is illegal in many places.

Comment: I blog from small city and here the only check registration and D/L

Comment: @Paulster2 I think he has an Avenger 220.

Comment: @Anarach - Thanks for that, but will bet it really doesn't matter to the OP as they haven't back to the site since the day after this question. I think Neil gives about a good of answer as can be expected.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have a Pulsar 220?  If so, you probably don't want two full-blown headlights, if the electrical system on a 220 is anything like that of the 135LS.  On my bike, the electricals can barely keep up with all the lights on, plus both signal lights blinking (unless I raise the idling speed).

You should probably look into adding accessory lights, instead.  For example, I've managed to attach two cheap bullet LEDs (mounted on the forks) and they work well enough that I sometimes forget to turn on my headlight.  Mounted in this manner, I've also managed to achieve a ["triangle of light"](http://www.motolight.com/page/481477660) that just might let me be a bit more visible to oncoming traffic.